# How do you have multiple UnityAppController overrides?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm using the Vuforia plugin within Unity 2018.1 and I have my own override for UnityAppController. When I do that the Vuforia one wipes out mine so it never gets called.

I found many possible solutions but the only one I've managed to get working is to manually replace the Vuforia one with one that also calls my own code too. Which is a total hack and not a good way forward.
I found this possible solution //[Can you have more than one subclass of UnityAppController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508476/can-you-have-more-than-one-subclass-of-unityappcontroller)

but I don't understand it.

```
#import "UnityAppController.h"

namespace {

typedef BOOL (*ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptionsImp)(UnityAppController *appController,
                                                            SEL selector,
                                                            UIApplication *application,
                                                            NSDictionary *launchOptions);

ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptionsImp OriginalApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions;

BOOL ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(UnityAppController *appController,
                          SEL selector,
                          UIApplication *application,
                          NSDictionary *launchOptions) {
    // Initialize Google Play Games, etc
    return OriginalApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(appController, selector, application, launchOptions);
}

IMP SwizzleMethod(SEL selector, Class klass, IMP newImp) {
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(klass, selector);
    if (method != nil) {
        return class_replaceMethod(klass, selector, newImp, method_getTypeEncoding(method));
    }
    return nil;
}

} // anonymous namespace

@interface AppController : UnityAppController

@end

@implementation AppController

+ (void)load {
    OriginalApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions = (ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptionsImp)
        SwizzleMethod(@selector(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:),
                      [UnityAppController class],
                      (IMP)&ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions);
}


@end
```

Where do you add your own code once you have swizzled the original?

This is the code I used to replace the Vuforia version:

```
 @implementation VuforiaNativeRendererController

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
 {
     //printf_console("Did Finish Launching with options\n");
     NSURL *URL = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
     if (URL)
     {
         const char *URLString = [URL.absoluteString UTF8String];
         //printf_console("Application started with URL:\n");
         //printf_console("%s\n", URLString);
         UnitySendMessage("Scripts", "openURLComplete", URLString);
     }
     BOOL ret = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
     if (ret)
     {
         _unityView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
     }
     return ret;
 }
```

But how would I introduce that using a "swizzle" method as above?